# C++ linked list append method

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I am writing a linked list template class in C++ as an exercise for myself to help me get back into C++ programming. I've got the following class definition:

```
template <typename T>
class List
{
public:
    List();
    ~List();

    void append(T data);
    void display();
    int  count();

private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node *next;
    } *head;
};
```

I have two versions of the append method - one that works and one that doesn't. I can't figure out what the difference, in terms of the operations performed, is, and why the second one doesn't work. Here's the one that works:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::append(T data)
{
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = new Node;
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *p = head, *q;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            q = p;
            p = p->next;
        }

        p = new Node;
        p->data = data;
        p->next = NULL;
        q->next = p;
    }
}
```

And here's the one that doesn't seem to actually add any elements to the list:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::append(T data)
{
    Node *p = head, *q = head;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        q = p;
        p = p->next;
    }

    p = new Node;
    p->data = data;
    p->next = NULL;
    if (q != NULL)
    {
        q->next = p;
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why the second version doesn't add any elements? I've been trying it with type T as int.

P.S. Neither version gives any errors or warnings during compilation, nor during runtime.

Comment: You could also keep a pointer (named e.g. tail) to the last element of the list, it makes appending easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method only handles the case where the list is non-empty.

When the list is empty, the line `q->next = p;` is never reached, so the new element is leaked with no pointer existing to it after `p` goes out of scope.

What you want, if you would like to eliminate the special case for empty list, is a `Node **`, like thus:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::append(T data)
{
    Node** q = &head; /* head acts as the first Node::next link */

    /* invariant: q points to some Node::next field (or head, which acts like one) */
    while (*q)
        q = &(*q)->next;

    /* invariant: q points to the Node::next field at the end of the chain, which is currently NULL */
    *q = new Node { data, nullptr };
}
```

Comment: The less pointers and double pointers in the code - the better. Your code shows that you can "do tricks" with C, but it is the code that is hard to read and maintain by others. KISS, remember?

Comment: Thanks, this has made it clear why it doesn't work. It's obvious now that just saying `Node *p = head` isn't enough to make `p = new Node` update head.

Comment: @littleadv: Inclusion of appropriate comments makes this code as easy to understand as the original, maybe easier.

Comment: The code won't be harder to read for someone who knows how to read C or C++.  I would think the bigger objection to the double-pointer is the quality of the object code it likely produces.  (The * operator is not free, and indirection can cost a lot if repeated in a long-running loop.)  On the other hand the source code is shorter and easier to read than code that doesn't use double-indirection.

Comment: @asveikau: The dominant cost comes from cache misses, and the cache behavior of the code using double-pointers should be identical to the original working code, the only difference is that in addition to accessing the `Node::next` variable, its address is also kept.  @littleadv has already pointed out the performance tradeoff of keeping a tail pointer, although making `tail` a `Node**` can eliminate the need for a special case there too.

Answer (score 0):

***In the first version you change the `head`, in the second - you don't.***

Simpler would be:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::append(T data)
{
    p = new Node;
    p->data = data;
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
}
```

That would also be more logical because entering an item to a linked list shouldn't take O(n) as it does for you...

If you absolutely have to add to the end, do this:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::append(T data)
{
    p = new Node;
    p->data = data;
    p->next = NULL;
    if (tail)
        tail->next = p;
    else // first time
        tail = head = p;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, my method is attempting to append a node to the end of the list. Yours is inserting one at the start. Secondly, as p is set to head at the start of the method, and if p is null the while loop is skipped, surely this is adding a new node at the head?

Comment: Yes, because as I said - insertion to the linked list shouldn't take O(n). If you insist on adding to the end - keep a pointer to the end, and then do the same.

Comment: The answer to the point of the question is the first sentence

Comment: Have you read the first sentence of my answer? It answers your question directly. I'll put it in bold for you.

Comment: You were aware? so why did you ask then? well, whatever.

Comment: So the real question should have been "why setting one variable doesn't change another variable". I assumed you have minimal knowledge of C, which was a mistake on my behalf, apparently. Are you originally a JAVA programmer?

Comment: No problem, I just suggested better way of doing things after answering your question and got a lot of complaints, I'm trying to understand why.